# Escaping a JOptionPane InputDialog loop using the cancel button

Tags: java, sql, arrays, arraylist, joptionpane

How would I go about adding a way for the loop to exit if the user clicks cancel. If anyone is willing there is a commented out section of code and it is referenced in the Tourist Input Button section of code but it doesnt work. Thanks

```
 /////////Convert
     public static int[] convertIntegers(java.util.List<Integer> elemIntegers)
{
    int[] elements = new int[elemIntegers.size()];
    for (int i=0; i < elements.length; i++)
    {
        elements[i] = elemIntegers.get(i).intValue();
    }
    return elements;
}
```

The full source code is here: http://pastebin.com/r4tEeatu

The specific section is

```
insertTableF.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int wayPoint1 = 0;
            int wayPoint2 = 0;
            int PassTime = 0;
            Statement statementR;

            if (loggedIn == 1) {

                while (passedR == 0) {
                    try {
                        if (wayPoint1 == 0) {
                            sTagR = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the Rhino Tag number:");
                            iTagR = Integer.parseInt(sTagR);
                            wayPoint1 = 1;
                        }
                        if (wayPoint2 == 0) {
                            sGPSX = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the horizontal GPS Grid Numbers(eg.3123):");
                            iGPS = Integer.parseInt(sGPSX);

                            wayPoint2 = 1;
                        }

                        sGPSY = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the vertical GPS Grid Letters(eg.XXYY:");
                        while (PassTime == 0) {
                            sTime = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the Last date you saw the Rhino(YYYY-MM-DD):");
                            //      if (!sTime.equals("") || sTime !=null){
                            if (isValidDate(sTime)) {
                                PassTime = 1;
                            } else {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please use the date format YYYY-MM-DD.");
                            }
                            //      } else {
                            //              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please use the date format YYYY-MM-DD.");
                            //      }
                        }
                        sLocation = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the Last place you saw the Rhino:");

                        passedR = 1;
                    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                        passedR = 0;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please use numbers for the Rhino Tag field.");
                    }
                }
                if (passedR == 1) {
                    ComboGPS = iGPS + " " + sGPSY;
                    try {
                        Connection insertTable = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={MicroSoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:/Users/Jethro/Desktop/IT Project Files/dbRhino.mdb", "", "");
                        String sql = "insert into TblRhinoLoc values ( '" + iTagR + "', '" + ComboGPS + "', '" + sTime + "', '" + sLocation + "')";

                        try {
                            statementR = insertTable.createStatement();
                            statementR.executeUpdate(sql);

                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data entered successfully!");
                            wayPoint1 = 0;
                            wayPoint2 = 0;
                        } catch (Exception err) {
                            System.out.println(err);
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, err);
                        }
                        UpdateJTableRanger();
                    } catch (SQLException er) {
                        System.out.println("Error: " + er);
                    }

                } else {

                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please make sure you are logged in before editing sensitive data.");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly which loop do you want to break out of?

I'm assuming you want to exit the `while (passedR == 0)` loop when the user cancels one of the `JoptionPane.showInputDialog` options.

```
while (passedR == 0) {
...
            sTagR = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...);
            if (sTagR == null) {
                 // User canceled.
                 break;
            } else {
               ...
            }
}
```